# How to make Chartjs charts responsive and look good on all screens inside an Angular application?

Tags: angular, frontend, chart.js

I am trying to display multiple charts using the Chart.js library inside an Angular app. This library uses a canvas element to display these charts. For example, I am trying to display a pie chart with labels and the pie chart itself [two charts with different numbers of labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiCSi.png)
When I try to add more labels, they wrap and shrink the chart itself. This also happens when displaying the charts on smaller screens. I tried changing the container size, but it doesn't affect the canvas size. My project has three files related to this issue:

1. dashbord.component.html : This file contains my custom charts component and passes it the attributes that Chart.js's canvas needs.

```
<!-- Charts -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-md-6" *ngFor="let chartConfig of chartConfigs">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div>
          <h4
          *ngIf="chartConfig.data.length === 0"
            class="card-title pt-3 px-2 text-warning"
            style="text-align: center"
          >
            No Data To Display.
          </h4>
          <app-chart
          *ngIf="chartConfig.data.length > 0"
            [chartType]="chartConfig.type"
            [chartData]="chartConfig.data"
            [chartLabels]="chartConfig.labels"
            [chartOptions]="chartConfig.options"
            [chartTitle]="chartConfig.title"
          ></app-chart>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. dashbord.component.ts : This file contains an array of four chart objects that contain the configuration of those charts.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Label } from "ng2-charts";
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from "chart.js";

interface ChartConfig {
  type: ChartType;
  data: ChartDataSets[];
  labels: Label[];
  options: ChartOptions;
  title: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-dashbord",
  templateUrl: "./dashbord.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./dashbord.component.scss"],
})
export class DashbordComponent implements OnInit {
  chartConfigs: ChartConfig[] = [
    {
      type: "doughnut",
      data: [
        {
          data: [40, 60],
          backgroundColor: [
            "#9C27B0", // Purple
            "#673AB7", // Deep Purple
            "#2196F3", // Blue
            "#00BCD4", // Cyan
            "#009688", // Teal
            "#4CAF50", // Green
            "#8BC34A", // Light Green
            "#FFC107", // Amber
            "#FF9800", // Orange
            "#FF5722", // Deep Orange
            "#607D8B", // Blue Grey
            "#BDBDBD", // Grey
            "#CFD8DC", // Silver
            "#ECEFF1", // White Smoke
            "#FAFAFA", // Off White
            "#F5F5F5", // White Smoke
            "#9E9E9E", // Dark Gray
            "#666666", // Medium Gray
            "#333333", // Dark Gray
          ],
        },
      ],
      labels: ["American Questions", "European Questions"],
      options: {
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            label: this.tooltipLabelCallback,
          },
        },
      },
      title: "Questions",
    },
    {
      type: "pie",
      data: [
        {
          data: [10, 35, 25, 5, 25],
          backgroundColor: [
            "#2196F3", // Blue
            "#00BCD4", // Cyan
            "#009688", // Teal
            "#4CAF50", // Green
            "#8BC34A", // Light Green
            "#FFC107", // Amber
            "#FF9800", // Orange
            "#FF5722", // Deep Orange
            "#607D8B", // Blue Grey
            "#BDBDBD", // Grey
            "#CFD8DC", // Silver
            "#ECEFF1", // White Smoke
            "#FAFAFA", // Off White
            "#F5F5F5", // White Smoke
            "#9E9E9E", // Dark Gray
            "#666666", // Medium Gray
            "#333333", // Dark Gray
          ], 
        }
      ],
      labels: [
        "Pulmonology",
        "Cardiothoracic Surgery",
        "Critical Care",
        "Gastroenterology",
        "Hepatology",
      ],
      options: {
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            label: this.tooltipLabelCallback,
          },
        },
      },
      title: "Specialization",
    },
    {
      type: "doughnut",
      data: [
        {
          data: [35, 25, 20, 15, 5],
          backgroundColor: [
            "#607D8B", // Blue Grey
            "#BDBDBD", // Grey
            "#CFD8DC", // Silver
            "#ECEFF1", // White Smoke
            "#F5F5F5", // White Smoke
            "#9E9E9E", // Dark Gray
            "#666666", // Medium Gray
            "#333333", // Dark Gray
          ],
        }
      ],
      labels: [
        "Riyadh",
        "Jeddah",
        "Mecca",
        "Al-Madinah al-Munawwarah",
        "Dammam",
      ],
      options: {
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            label: this.tooltipLabelCallback,
          },
        },
      },
      title: "Cities",
    },
    {
      type: "doughnut",
      data: [
        {
          data: [5, 7, 9, 10, 13, 5, 7, 9, 10, 13, 5, 7, 9, 10, 13],
          backgroundColor: [
            "#607D8B", // Blue Grey
            "#BDBDBD", // Grey
            "#CFD8DC", // Silver
            "#9E9E9E", // Dark Gray
            "#666666", // Medium Gray
            "#333333", // Dark Gray
          ],
        }
      ],
      labels: [
        "   King Fahad Medical",
        "Abdul Lateef Jameel Hospital",
        "Almana General Hospital",
        "Saudi German Hospital",
        "Saudi National Hospital",
        "   King Fahad Medical",
        "Abdul Lateef Jameel Hospital",
        "Almana General Hospital",
        "Saudi German Hospital",
        "Saudi National Hospital",
        "   King Fahad Medical",
        "Abdul Lateef Jameel Hospital",
        "Almana General Hospital",
        "Saudi German Hospital",
        "Saudi National Hospital",
      ],
      options: {
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            label: this.tooltipLabelCallback,
          },
        },
      },
      title: "Hospitals",
    },
  ];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  tooltipLabelCallback(tooltipItem, data): string {
    // Calculate the total of all data points
    const total = data.datasets[0].data.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0);
    const currentValue = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index];
    // Calculate the percentage and format it
    const percentage = ((currentValue / total) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";
    // Return the label for the tooltip
    return data.labels[tooltipItem.index] + ": " + percentage;
  }
}
```

3. chart.component.ts : This file contains the canvas itself.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Color } from "ng2-charts";
import { ChartOptions } from "chart.js";

@Component({
  selector: "app-chart",
  template: `
    <div>
      <div>{{ chartTitle }}</div>
      <div *ngIf="chartType == 'doughnut'">
        <canvas
          baseChart
          [chartType]="chartType"
          [datasets]="chartData"
          [labels]="chartLabels"
          [options]="chartOptions"
        ></canvas>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="chartType == 'pie'">
        <canvas
          baseChart
          [chartType]="chartType"
          [datasets]="chartData"
          [labels]="chartLabels"
          [options]="chartOptions"
        ></canvas>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="chartType == 'bar'">
        <canvas
          baseChart
          [chartType]="chartType"
          [datasets]="chartData"
          [labels]="chartLabels"
          [options]="chartOptions"
        ></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./chart.component.scss']
})
export class ChartComponent {
  @Input() chartType: string;
  @Input() chartData: any[];
  @Input() chartLabels: string[];
  @Input() chartOptions: ChartOptions;
  // @Input() chartColors: Color[];
  @Input() chartTitle: string;
}
```

When I try to add more labels, they wrap and shrink the chart itself. This also happens when displaying the charts on smaller screens. I tried changing the container size, but it doesn't affect the canvas size.
[changing the container size, but it doesn't affect the canvas size.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCQIW.png)